# Android visible elapsed time (updated by second)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to display the elapsed time in an activity ( timer restricted to the activity)
No problem in checking the passage of time with

```
SystemClock.CurrentThreadTimeMillis
```

However I don't know how to update the Fragment where I have the display. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Call Fragment in a Thread and invoke the thread For a given time invervel

Comment: final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that a class called [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) exists that does exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by looking into either [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html), either of which should be able to help you do what you seem to want.  Your question is kind of vague, so the best I can do is point you in the right direction.

Comment: Kinda similar to yours but exactly what I was looking for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using support fragments:

`getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container).updateView(time)`

if not, use:

`getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container).updateView(time)`

Where `R.id.frag_container` is the frame holding your fragment.
      `updateView(Time t)` is a method in your fragment.

If you are not using a frame, and the fragment is embedded in your activity by using `<fragment.../>` in your xml, then you just use `R.id.fragId`